# Flink Kafka job with Boundedness set to the latests offsets not working properly

Tags: apache-flink

We have two simple Flink jobs using Kafka connector:

- first is reading a file and sending its content to Kafka topic
- second is reading all previously uploaded records from Kafka and counts them

When we are creating `KafkaSource` for consuming records we are setting Boundedness to the latest offset like this:

```
 KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource
            .builder()
            .setTopics(...)
            .setBootstrapServers(...)
            .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
            .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
            .setDeserializer(...)
            .setGroupId(...)
            .build();
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected and the consumer job just hangs.

My observation is that if the producer app is using `AT_LEAST_ONCE` semantic then everything is fine and the consumer works as expected, the problem occurs only when the producer is using `EXACTLY_ONCE` semantic.
Additionally, when I'm running a producer job locally (using IDE), everything works fine as well (in both `EXACTLY_ONCE`  and `AT_LEAST_ONCE` modes), the problem is visible only when the producer job is run on the Ververica Platform.

Comment: What happens if you run with parallelism 1?

Comment: Still the same, consumer app just hangs (I set parallelism 1 for both producer and consumer job)